# cut fill arcgis 10.1 doesn't works

Tags: arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing, error, 3d-analyst

I have a problem with ArcGIS 10.1: 
I have two TINs and I want to execute [Cut Fill (3D Analyst) tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q90000001z000000) :

Data:

[image: data]

Adding data to ArcScene:

[image: Adding data to ArcScene]

[image: Adding data to ArcScene]

Tool:

[image: Tool]

Result: Problem

[image: Problem]

I did the same thing in ArcGIS 9.3 and it's works, I don't know where is the problem, can somebody help?

Comment: first thing to test in your case is to use smaller names and avoid special characters in it (e.g. "-").

Comment: i changed the name but it still not working @radouxju

Answer (score 3):

i solved the problem by converting the tow TIN to a raster before execute the cut fill 3D analyst tool :

- [image]

Answer (score -1):

Use the Surface Difference tool in the Triangulated Surface toolbox inside 3D analyst.  It is the same as Spatial Analyst Cut/Fill tool for rasters